# How to create a generic way to load files?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony2, even though I knew symfony 1.4.

In my new project, I need a way to be able to load data from various text files (csv, xml, other), from various locations, in the most generic way possible, i.e. adding a new file to be checked should only require some configuration.

What's the symfon-iest way of doing that ?

Comment: Create a bundle for that, and add configuration to it. Next to that there is nothing symfony specific to your case, the core libraries don't have configurable file and file-system abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I don't know of the implementation details for Symfony specifically; [Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette) is a good PHP5 file system layer abstraction layer and they [provide a Symfony bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle) so it should be easy to get up and running. There are also details on getting it going on Symfony 2 in the [read me documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/blob/master/README.markdown) (scroll down).

You can easily add your own drivers for other file systems such as S3 (already implemented in base package).

Comment: +1: A useful suggestion. Configuration in the question could be the whole "file system".